# Using lightning:actionOverride and getting URL parameters of the clicked button (defaultFieldValues)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button, button-overrides, default-value, lightning-action-override

I have a New button override set to send all New requests to a custom Lightning Component. This works fine.

However, I have several buttons with defaultFieldValues set to prepopulate fields. Since the lightning:actionOverride component is in place, these new fields are ignored.  I am hoping to see in the component that some parameters in the URL are set and thus bypass the custom component and then redirect to that URL (by recreating it).  Maybe there is a better solution..

**I am unable to get any custom parameters from the initial URL in the component.**

In my controller I've tried this, but it seems that the parameters set on the initial button URL don't make it this far:

```
doInit : function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var pageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
    console.log( 'Pagereference is ' + JSON.stringify( pageRef ) );
}
```

The custom button hack looks like this:

```
/lightning/o/Case/new?recordTypeId=XXX&test=456defaultFieldValues=Subject=TEST123
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to bypass the custom component override for these URL buttons, you can do this by simply adding a `nooverride=1` parameter to the URL

Like this:

```
/lightning/o/Case/new?nooverride=1&recordTypeId=XXX&test=456defaultFieldValues=Subject=TEST123
```

Adding this parameter will bypass your custom override, leaving the standard new buttons pointing to your override component!

If you wanted to receive these defaults into a custom component and use them as part of your custom component, then the solution would be to make your component URL addressable, then update the URL buttons to point to your custom component's URL with these default values passed into it, thereby allowing you to read the parameters and work with them in your component.

Comment: We want the normal "New" Button on the cases page to lead to the custom component - is this still possible this way?

Comment: Re-read your use case and updated my answer, check it out! :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding `?nooverride=1` as the first parameter for the custom URL that I want to bypass the New button LEX Override and therefore skip the lightning component, but it still directs there.  Here is my URL: `/lightning/o/Case/new?nooverride=1&recordTypeId=XXX&defaultFieldValues=Subject=Sales%20Support%20Requested%20for%20{!Opportunity.Name}`